# Network is unreachable when installing rvm

Tags: rvm

I try to install rvm, but I hit "Network is unreachable" when I run the following command:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

gpg: keyserver receive failed: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was blocked by the same thing for a week. Finally finding this Reddit thread, which seems like the simplest explanation so far: https://www.reddit.com/r/GnuPG/comments/o5tb6a/keyservers_are_gone/ ...switching to `keys.openpgp.org` finally worked for me.

I had googled a lot and nothing at the top results worked. I tried the different hostnames, adding `:80` port specification, prefixing `0x` on the key signatures, and so on. Today I finally found that thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just to share how I solved, since accepted answer does not work for me:

1 - export the public key

```
gpg --export email@gmail.com > my_key.pub
```

2 - use the web interface at `https://keys.openpgp.org/upload/submit` to upload the certificate

I hope this help.